# the shape of feed data does not match the shape of the placeholder in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a error when I implement the XOR with tensorflow. The error message indicates that the shape of input data does not match the shape of the placeholder. The code is following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,2])
data = np.random.rand(2,2)
print data.shape
print data
y = tf.add(x,x)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(y,{x:data})
print sess.run(y)
```

The error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,2]

[[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one. You just need to provide the feed_dict to populate `x` in your final `sess.run` call. This error occurs because the graph must execute all the way through the `tf.Tensor` provided to `sess.run()`. Because `y` depends on `x` and `x` is a placeholder, you must provide a `feed_dict` to your `sess.run()` call.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

data = np.random.rand(2, 2)

y = tf.add(x, x)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Note that I'm saving the output of the sess.run call.
y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: data})

# Here's your bug. You haven't provided a feed_dict in the line below.
# print(sess.run(y))
print("y_out")
print(y_out)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a grammar error. The correct code should be:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,2])
data = np.random.rand(2,2)
print data.shape
print data
y = tf.add(x,x)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
y_result = sess.run(y,{x:data})
print y_result
```